# Toss a fair coin. Payoff is $2^z$ where $z$ is the number of tails that occur before the first head. What is the expected value?

Tags: statistics

> In this game toss a fair coin and wait till the first head appears. Payoff is $2^z$ where $z$ is the number of tails that occur before the first head. What is the expected value?

So I have the probability of getting $x$ tails and then a head as the geometric distribution

$(\frac{1}{2})^{x+1}$ , where $X~Geometric(\frac{1}{2})$. which has $E(X)=\frac{1-1/2}{1/2}=1$

So I believe I want $Z$ where $Z=2^X$?

$E(Z)=E(2^X)$ I'm really unsure of how to deal with this though?

Do I have this?

$E(Z)=E(2^X)=\sum_z 2^x(P(2^X=z))$

Comment: See the [Saint Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to receive $2^0$, $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to receive $2^1$, $\frac{1}{8}$ chance to receive $2^2$.....

So your expected payoff is just $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n2^n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}1=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^i 2^i$$

Comment: That's not too hard to simplify....